# Java EE без GlassFish

Tags: java-ee, glassfish, java

Привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скачать **Java EE 6 SDK** без **GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2.**

Я собираюсь использовать его с Tomcat, а на сайте [Оракла](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html), он везде в перемешку с этим сервером.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html

Comment: но я это качал
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Tomcat вам не нужен Java EE 6 SDK. Вам возможно потребуется для компиляции проекта Servlet API и возможно другие части EE (например JMS, если вы собираетесь его использовать). Соответствующие библиотеки обычно есть в Maven-репозиториях.

Такие вещи как JDBC и JMX, которые раньше были частью EE, теперь присутствуют в Java SE из коробки.

Comment: Спасибо вам. Я с вопросом поторопился немного. В принципе так и думал, но ваш ответ окончательно меня убедил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот можете посмотреть как с Tomcat сделать свое веб приложение http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0y-6On2qeg